# Shared root to "bobech", "bobbin" and "bobby"?

Tags: etymology, nouns, roots

Is there a shared etymological root to the following words?

- *Bobech* (glass collar on a candle)
- *Bobbin* (in a sewing machine)
- *Bobby* [pin] (woman's hair pin)

I just learned the word *bobech* last night, and it made me wonder, simply due to the phonetic similarities.

Comment: Unlikely - [bobèche](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bobeche) is just a current French word (candlestick collar, drip-tray, bracket). [Bobbin](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bobbin) is from Middle French *bobine - hank of thread*. They may be connected, but [bobby pin](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=bobby+pin) is probably just a diminutive "bob" as in "short hair" *perhaps of Celtic origin (cf. Ir. baban "tassel, cluster," Gael. babag).*

Comment: @FumbleFingers That’s an answer, not a comment. :)

Comment: @tchrist: I've no idea, really. I guessed "unlikely", after a minute or so on Google, but perhaps all three bob's do have something in common. The drip-tray thingy is a bit like a headband for stopping sweat (rather than wax/oil) dripping. And that could relate to a tassel. Which ties hair up in a bun... Let someone else who knows more about it (or can be bothered to do more research) pronounce.

Comment: Only if you found anything beyond "the phonetic similarities" and more promising can we suspect anything. Else it is a frivolous pursuit.

Comment: Fumblefingers you are... bashful! adorable and rare quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they don't have a shared root.

### *bobbin*

Of *bobbin* (in a sewing machine), the [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=bobbin&allowed_in_frame=0) says:

> 1520s, from Fr. *bobine*, small instrument used in sewing or tapestry-making, perhaps from L. *balbus* (see babble) for the stuttering, stammering noise it made.

### *bobby [pin]*

Of *bobby [pin]* (a woman's hair pin), the [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=bobby%20pin&allowed_in_frame=0) says:

> 1928, from dim. of *bob* (2) + *pin* (n.).

Where [*bob* (2)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=bob&allowed_in_frame=0) is:

> "short hair," 1680s, attested 1570s in sense of "a horse's tail cut short," from earlier *bobbe* "cluster" (as of leaves), mid-14c., a northern word, perhaps of Celtic origin (cf. Ir. *baban* "tassel, cluster," Gael. *babag*). Used over the years in various senses connected by the notion of "round, hanging mass," e.g. the meaning "weight at the end of a line" (1650s). The hair sense was revived with a shift in women's styles early 20c. (verb 1918, noun 1920). Related words include *bobby pin, bobby sox, bobsled, bobcat*.

### *bobeche*

Neither *bobech* or *bobeche* are in the Online Etymology Dictionary or Oxford English Dictionary, but [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/bobeche) says *bobeche* (with an -e) (a glass collar on a candle) is from the French *bobèche*.

Comment: Interesting. So `bobby pin` is actually - it sounds like - related to the bob on a fishing line, too. I'll definitely be bookmarking that Etym. Dict. link, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked and answered many moons ago, but I also was curious as to the word origin of bobeche (not just that it's borrowed from the French word meaning the same thing).

After some fruitless digging (and in the process stumbling across this question), I located one source that suspects that *bobbin* may also be etymologically related. I wonder if @eidylon was editing dictionary.com. :-)

[ORIGIN OF BOBÈCHE](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/bobeche)
1895–1900; < French, of uncertain origin; bob- perhaps akin to the base of bobine bobbin